# Docusign: Use API to upload document and request signatures in a sequential flow

Tags: docusignapi

I've been looking at the API docs on Docusign (e.g. https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/envelopes) but finding it pretty unclear.

I would like to:

1. Upload a document (e.g. pdf or docx)
2. Email signatory #1 that it needs to be signed
3. Know when they sign e.g. a webbook
4. Email the next signatory that it's their turn to sign it

I don't want to add all the people who need to sign it at once, but request them one by one (or multiple at each stage).

Can someone please point me in the right direction for doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend checking out DocuSign's Quickstart examples in your favorite language: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/quickstart-request-signature-email

To have signatories receive the envelope sequentially, you'll want to define a routing order for each recipient. DocuSign automatically moves through the routing order, so after signer 1 completes their portion, signer 2 will be notified.

To receive a notification to your webhook listener, you'll want to look in to DocuSign Connect: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/connect